# PHP lithium(li3) how to find out version

Tags: php, lithium

If I have a lithium app that I did not set up how do I find out the version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think they put a timestamp on the files themselves. 
I would suggest you look at the test cases and look at the most recent timestamp.

Comment: it seems like they in fact don't have a good way to keep track of currently used version. Thank you.

Comment: @Evgenius greut's way is the easiest, but you need to know how to use git, and the source needs to be a git clone. If the above is true, then you can run the git log and it should have the time stamp in addition to the commit info.

Answer (score 2):

If your using it via `git submodules`, it's pretty easy.

```
$ cd libraries/lithium
$ git log -1 | grep commit
commit 97be2347d5a2e9b096db44c009df79ee9b6c0199
```

Which is, in this case, the 0.10: https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/tags

I dunno if it makes sense to have strict version numbers in the pre-1.0 state. Everything can and might break during an upgrade.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately for me I don't use lithium via git subversion.

Comment: then find when did you put the directory there.